# Бодяга

Tags: фразеология

Бодяга - это пресноводная губка, используемая в медицине. Но почему это слово стало нарицательным, причем, его значение никакого отношения не имеет ни к губке, ни к медицине?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Разводить бодягу" или просто "бодяга" в значении "вздорные, пустые разговоры", "бесполезные действия", "ерунда" и проч. пришло в язык из уголовного жаргона (фени), этимология в таких случаях часто затруднена, поскольку всегда есть ненулевая вероятность, что слово имеет еврейские (иврит, реже - идиш), цыганские или ещё какие-нибудь "экзотические" корни.

Но в данном случае можно предположить, что разведение бодяги (губки) дело довольно хлопотное и небыстрое. Это подтверждают косметические рецепты. А вот эффект от примения такого "раствора" (на самом деле - взвеси) весьма спорен.

Правда, подозреваю, что тут могло быть и "разведение" в значении "действия по увеличению численности", "воспроизводство". Судя по всему, это дело совсем уж неблагодарное и пустое.